# Gnome with Xmonad crashes on login

Tags: gnome, xmonad

I recently discovered Xmonad, and installed it on all of my computers; however, on my desktop computer, vanilla xmonad has mirrored screens and poor resolution. The 'gnome with xmonad' desktop environment seems to be the only way for me to use xmonad, while also utilising my dual screens and showing crisp visuals.

To the problem. Every time I login with gnome xmonad, I am logged out again within a minute. Contrast that with vanilla xmonad, which has been on all day with no problem; and basic Cinnamon, which would often crash (not just log out) my computer.

To the question. I'm looking for some way to either extend xmonad to use both screens, with a reasonable resolution; or stop gnome xmonad from quitting on me.

Addendum: my (minimal) xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig
```

Edit:
From [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/smooth-font-rendering-with-xmonad-in-linux-mint), I've been able to use the `gnome-settings-daemon` while in xmonad, which doesn't seem to cause either a crash or a logout, but does throw some scary warnings when I start it:

```
** (gnome-settings-daemon:2114): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
(gnome-settings-daemon:2114): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Grab failed for some keys, another application may already have access the them.
```

Now I need a way to run that command whenever xmonad starts, assuming those warnings are harmless.

Comment: `gnome` with `xmonad` is packaged differently on different systems, which distro are you using?  The most common way that gnome is added to xmonad is by `import XMonad.Config.Gnome` in `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`, how does that file looks?  Also, `gnome 3` still has some outstanding issues with `xmonad`  because of the `gnome-sessions`.  Are you using GDM (Gnome Display Manager) to enter a `gnome-session`?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 17.3. My xmonad.hs file is included under addendum. I have never heard of GDM, and start Gnome With Xmonad from the login screen.

Comment: Apologies for that, i'm used to much bigger `xmonad.hs` files.  I booted a Mint 17.3 and had a lot of issues to actually compile a xmonad session.  Can you actually run `xmonad --recompile` as your user?  That shall be possible to run from within any other window manager or even a tty.  (Also, GDM *is* the login screen, i assume you never changed it to something else)

Comment: Yes, I did and am able to successfully run `xmonad --recompile`. No, I never manually changed the login manager.

Comment: Cool, that means you got through the installation of `libghc-xmonad-dev` and `ghc` to actually get the haskell pieces needed to start `xmonad`.  I struggled with it half my Sunday but `gnome3` got the best of me.  I used `xmonad` with `gnome2` for years but `gnome3` with the new GDM is too quirky for me, sorry.  Apparently `fedora` made it work of the box, if you do not mind switching distros you might try that instead.